# Material UI TextField customization

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, customization, textfield

I сannot customize label in TextField component. Styles do not apply to label in [TextField](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) component. What am I doing wrong?

```js
    import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
    import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
    import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

    const StyledTextField = withStyles({
        root: {},
        label: {
            textTransform: 'uppercase'
        }
    })(TextField)

    class App extends PureComponent {
        render() {
            return (
                <StyledTextField
                    id='city-of-residence'
                    label='Город проживания'
                    fullWidth={true}
                    margin='normal'
                    helperText='helperText'/>
            )
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

**Expected result =)**

[image]

**Current result =(**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add property `InputLabelProps={{ style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }}` to the `TextField` or add this CSS class:

```css
"& .MuiInputLabel-root":{
    textTransform: "uppercase"
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

hi you can use your custom react element inside label like below

```
 <StyledTextField
                    id='city-of-residence'
                    label={<p style={{textTransform: 'uppercase'}}>Город проживания</p>}
                    fullWidth={true}
                    margin='normal'
                    helperText='helperText'/>
            )
```

Comment: Yeahh, now I'm doing in similar way:
```InputLabelProps={{style: {textTransform: 'uppercase'}}}```

Comment: But this is the path to the dark side

Comment: @north.inhale what is the light side way?

Answer (score -1):

You can use in css **text-transform: uppercase;**